# Finding Ceiling of a BST

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree, ceil

I am trying to implement a function to find the ceiling of a key in a BST.  I do not understand the logic behind this code, and whenever I try to find the ceiling of a key that is not already present in the BST, I get a segmentation fault.  Can someone explain what is going on?  How would I implement this properly?  Note: Internal method is sourced from GeeksForGeeks.  Thank you in advance!

Internal Method:

```
template <typename T>
typename BST<T>::Node *BST<T>::Ceil(std::unique_ptr<Node> &n, T 
key) {
if (!n) {
     std::cout << "return null" << std::endl;
     return nullptr;
  }
  if (n->key == key) {
    std::cout << "Same key found" << std::endl;
    return n.get();
  } else if (n->key < key) {
    return Ceil(n->right, key);
  }

   Node * ceil = Ceil(n->left, key);
  return (ceil->key >= key) ? ceil : n.get();

}
```

External Method:

```
template <typename T>
const K& BST<T>::Ceil(const K &key) {
  std::cout << "Main Ceil" << std::endl;
  return Ceil(root, key)->key;
}
```

Comment: `return Ceil(root, key)->key;` If the `Ceil` function returns `nullptr` you have an error.

Comment: I understand that, but code returns nullptr when I do not expect it to.   I'm not sure why.

Comment: The function would return the first entry where the key is the equal or greater than your search value. If there is no such entry in the tree, it will return a nullptr. If it does not work as expected, use a debugger to step through the function.